# Write whole Android shared_preferences.xml at once

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Is it possible to write a whole shared_preferences.xml at once?

I want to realize a kind of settings import/export, so i need to read and write the whole file without loosing the xml-tags.

Reading the file is easy, but when i write my values (using PrintWriter) the old values stored in memory overwrite them seconds later.

what can i do to prevent that without writing single values using preference editor.

Comment: Have you tried Android BackupManager. It is not a manual backup service but it is much more useful I think. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/BackupManager.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the BackupManager doesn't work for me. I have to post my preferences to an online server which changes something and gives me the whole xml back.

Comment: As far as I know, the memory management to sharedpreferences is available after API level 9. After that, all the changes are written in memory and later to the disk. You may search for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I read it from a file designed like Android's own preferences.xml and write it successively in my own function like this:

```
public static void preferencesImport(String PreferenceFilepath) {
    preferencesImportPreferenceFilepath = PreferenceFilepath;
    try {
        // Parsing
        // see http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/xml/android-simple-xml-dom-parser/
        XMLParserHelper parser = new XMLParserHelper(); // reference to described XMLDOMParser helper class
        BufferedInputStream stream;
        try {
            stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(preferencesImportPreferenceFilepath));
            org.w3c.dom.Document doc = parser.getDocument(stream);

            // string value
            NodeList nodeListString = doc.getElementsByTagName("string");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeListString.getLength(); i++) {
                Element eString = (Element) nodeListString.item(i);
                Pref.setString(eString.getAttribute("name"), eString.getTextContent()); // Own getter/setter -> use Android's preference manager instead in similar way
            }

            // repeat code above for boolean, long, int, float values

            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // output IOException
        } catch (Throwable t1) {
            // output Throwable1
        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (Throwable t2) {
        // output Throwable2
    }
}
```